# VkSurfaceKHR does not to update when resizing xcb window

Tags: resize, vulkan, xcb

I have followed the tutorial at https://vulkan-tutorial.com... I created it without using the GLFW etension. So far I'm up to "Swap chain Recreation", and all is setup and rendering correctly.

However, I can't seem to get resizing working correctly!

I've hooked into the `XCB_RESIZE_REQUEST` and am setting my info struct w/h like so:

```
if (resize->width > 0) { info.width = resize->width; }
if (resize->height > 0) { info.height = resize->height; }
info.framebufferResized = true;
```

Which causes (in the next `drawFrame()` call) `recreateSwapchain()` to be called:

```
if (res == VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DATE_KHR || res == VK_SUBOPTIMAL_KHR || info.framebufferResized) {
    info.framebufferResized = false;
    recreateSwapchain();
} else  if (res != VK_SUCCESS) {
    throw runtime_error("failed to present swap chain image!");
}

recreateSwapchain() {
    vkDeviceWaitIdle(info.device);

    cleanupSwapchain();

    querySwapchainSupport(info.physicalDevice);
    createSwapchain();
    createImageViews();
    createRenderPass();
    createGraphicsPipeline();
    createFramebuffers();
    createCommandBuffers();
}
```

I've done some debugging, and have found that the `swapchainSupport.capabilities.minImageExtent.width` (and height) do not change from the initial values!.. That is, this call

```
querySwapchainSupport(VkPhysicalDevice physicalDevice) {
    VkResult res = vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR(
        physicalDevice, info.surface, &info.swapchainSupport.capabilities);
    assert(res == VK_SUCCESS);
```

Does not update the `info.swapchainSupport.capabilities` with new window size.

Any help, or comments would be greatly appreciated.

Example Screenshot:

[image: after resize]

Comment: I'd rather not resort to using a library such as GLFW.. as I'll most likely want to target mobile at some point;

Comment: Why are you looking at `minImageExtent` instead of `currentExtent`?

Comment: current, min, and max all stay the same: 800x600

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure if `XCB_RESIZE_REQUEST` is the right event to wait for. In my examples I use `XCB_CONFIGURE_NOTIFY` to check for window resize events, and querying the surface capabilities after that event gives me the new window size as the surface capabilities extents as expected:

```
case XCB_CONFIGURE_NOTIFY:
{
    const xcb_configure_notify_event_t *cfgEvent = (const xcb_configure_notify_event_t *)event;
    if (((cfgEvent->width != width) || (cfgEvent->height != height)))
    {
            destWidth = cfgEvent->width;
            destHeight = cfgEvent->height;
            if ((destWidth > 0) && (destHeight > 0))
            {
                // Swap chain recreation ins done in this function              
                windowResize();                 
            }
    }
}
```

You also need to add the accompanying flag at XCB window creation time:

```
uint32_t value_list[32];
value_list[1] = ... | XCB_EVENT_MASK_STRUCTURE_NOTIFY...

xcb_create_window(connection,
    ...     
    value_list);
```

This has been tested to work on many different Linux implementations and platforms.

If you need some help getting XCB up and running you may want to take a look at my [Vulkan samples](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan). The interesting parts are in the [example base class](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/master/base/vulkanexamplebase.cpp#L1818) and the  [swapchain header](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/master/base/VulkanSwapChain.hpp).

Comment: Yup, the same is performed in the "API without Secrets" series of Intel's Vulkan tutorials. Have a look [here](https://github.com/GameTechDev/IntroductionToVulkan/blob/master/Project/Common/OperatingSystem.cpp).

Comment: That Worked! Very Good! Does this have something to do with adding to `XCB_EVENT_MASK_STRUCTURE_NOTIFY` to the value_list?